# Multi-Dimensional Array if array elements are missing in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this kind of multi-dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [911111111111] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [error_row] => Array
        (
            [0] => 911111111111
        )

)
```

The problem is I got an error

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So I tried to put an `(array)` in foreach()

so far what I tried is

```
foreach((array)$check_cloud_id_exist as $key)
{
   foreach((array)$key as $subkey){
      foreach((array)$subkey as $childkey){
         foreach((array)$childkey as $childitem => $childs){
             //code here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It gives me a loop array with one element containing the boolean value as an int which is not present in `[error_row]`

Comment: You should use `recursive` function to get proper values.

Comment: @SumonSarker you mean array_walk_recursive?

Comment: Let me know, Do you want to make 'Tree List' from the array?

Comment: I dont exactly know what you mean but I want to get the end of `[return]` which is **1** and end of `[error_row]` which is 911111111111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `Recursive Function` Example to get All `Key`,`Value` from associative array in PHP.

```
$YourArray = [
  'return'=>[
    [
        [
            '911111111111'=>1
        ]
    ]
  ],
  'error_row'=>[
    '911111111111'
  ]
];

#print_r($YourArray);

function RecursiveFunc($array){
  if (is_array($array)) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo "Key   : ".$key.PHP_EOL; #Get The Key
            RecursiveFunc($value);
        }else{
            echo "Value : ".$value.PHP_EOL; #Get The Value
        }
    }
  }else{
    echo "Value : ".$array.PHP_EOL; #Get The Value
  }
}

RecursiveFunc($YourArray);
```

> **Note:** Above Function will give you all `key`,`value` from `$YourArray`

**Here is your solution**

```
$end_of_return = '';

if (is_array($array['return'])) {
  $last_array_index   = count($array['return'])-1;
  $another_last_index = count($array['return'][$last_array_index])-1;
  $end_of_return = $array['return'][$last_array_index][$another_last_index];
}

$end_of_error_row = end($array['error_row']);

var_dump($end_of_return,$end_of_error_row);
```

Comment: but how can I get the value of it?

Comment: Ok, Wait, I am updating the Answer @PureRhymerOrganization